# formvalidation.io hidden fields internet explorer bug

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using https://formvalidation.io/ for my form validations and have come across a bug related with earlier versions of internet explorer...

See the original developers basic example: https://formvalidation.io/guide/plugins/excluded/

I have recreated this on my test site: http://test.petewinter.com/test.php

If you are using a modern browser. You will notice that when you fill out the fullname and company fields (without showing the hidden fields) then click submit you will get an alert message.

This does not happen when using some earlier versions of IE. I tested using Windows 10 IE version 15 via browserstack.com

The problem seems to be due to the hidden fields as if you click the "more info" link to show the hidden fields it works in earlier versions of IE. So the problem seems to be the formvalidation.io exclude plugin does not work with these browsers.

Can you please help me find a fix or a work around for these browsers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share a minimal example of your code demonstration the problem. Make sure to include the code in your question and not on an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to [this article](https://formvalidation.io/guide/developing/custom-validator/) to create a custom Validator, you could check whether the Job title and a Department text box is hidden or not first, then based on the result to validate the value.